# Direct browser to log in to GeoServer

Tags: geoserver

I am embedding GeoServer's web UI in an IFrame and want to automatically log the user in.  Is it possible to include the login credentials in a query like this `http//:host:port/geoserver/login?username=usr&password=pass`?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are aware that you can authenticate using the standard HTTP Authentication mechanism? That's what's recommended for programmatic access rather than the cookie based authentication used by browsers and the Web UI.

Comment: Also, the URI you provided looks more like you're thinking of GET than POST.

Comment: Yes, it's a GET URI, sorry.
My intente is to log in geoserver using the credentials of a user logon gatein portal. That is, I get the username and the password and I want to send it to geoserver in order to get logon.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following you.  Are you saying you want your web application to direct a user's browser to GeoServer and automatically log them in?

Comment: Yes, it's. I will try to explain my problem more clearly. I add the geoserver web administration to a page in the gatein portal using a iframe portlet.Now I want that, when the portal's user navigate to the page that contains the iframe, he is already logged in geoserver with the username and password that he have introduced in gatein.

Sorry for my english, but isn't my native language.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. 
Using this script code  I resolved my problem:

```
function post_to_url(params) 
    {
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
        form.setAttribute("action", "http://host:port/geoserver/j_spring_security_check");

        for(var key in params) {
            if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
             }
        }
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
```